# Index was out of range, must be non-negative error while printing Grid view in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am trying to print gridview data in c#. but i am having error
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

My code example is

**// Load data to Grid view**

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        db.cnTransact.Open();
        SqlCommand cm;
        try
        {
            string catName = "Single Gas Clip Personal Monitor (SGC)";
            string sql = "SELECT item_id, noun, category, type, partNo  from tbl_items where category='"+catName+"' ";
            cm = new SqlCommand(sql, db.cnTransact);

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                object[] row = { sqlReader[0], sqlReader[1], sqlReader[2], sqlReader[3], sqlReader[4] };
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
              //  grd_singlgasmonitor.Rows.Add(row);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Print Button Code**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
        printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

        //Get the document
        if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            printDocument1.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
```

**Printing Events code**

```
 private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            strFormat = new StringFormat();
            strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

            arrColumnLefts.Clear();
            arrColumnWidths.Clear();
            iCellHeight = 0;
            iRow = 0;
            bFirstPage = true;
            bNewPage = true;

            // Calculating Total Widths
            iTotalWidth = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Set the left margin
            int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            //Set the top margin
            int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            //Whether more pages have to print or not
            bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
            int iTmpWidth = 0;

            //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
            if (bFirstPage)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                                   (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                                   ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                    iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                                GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                    // Save width and height of headres
                    arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                    arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                    iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
                }
            }
            //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
            while (iRow <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow GridRow = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow];
                //Set the cell height
                iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;
                int iCount = 0;
                //Check whether the current page settings allo more rows to print
                if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
                {
                    bNewPage = true;
                    bFirstPage = false;
                    bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bNewPage)
                    {
                        //Draw Header
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Customer Summary", new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Customer Summary", new Font(dataGridView1.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        //Draw Date
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView1.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Customer Summary", new Font(new Font(dataGridView1.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        //Draw Columns                 
                        iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                            iCount++;
                        }
                        bNewPage = false;
                        iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                    }
                    iCount = 0;
                    //Draw Columns Contents                
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                    {
                        if (Cel.Value != null)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                            new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                            new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],(float)iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
                        }
                        //Drawing Cells Borders 
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                                iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                        iCount++;
                    }
                }
                iRow++;
                iTopMargin += iCellHeight;
            }

            //If more lines exist, print another page.
            if (bMorePagesToPrint)
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I am having Error at Line

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                            new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                            new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],(float)iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
```

Compiler / IDE is not getting value of (int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], I tried debugging. It is showing Null value in arrColumLefts[iCount]

Please tell me how can i solve this

Thanks
Sajid

Comment: What is the value of `iCount` at that point? It is probably equal to or greater than the number of columns you have.

Comment: @Andrew Arnold Friend Value of iCount varies as control/pointer moves across Grid view rows and columns but before value of iCount is incremented from 0 to 1. App crashes showing above Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see solution to a similar question at http://codingresolved.com/discussion/2729/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-collection-print-gridview/p1 I am sure that this will help you in your issue